Windows 10 Pro now requires activation after each reboot
This started about 3 months ago, on an old Dell Inspiron 660. I had made no hardware changes at or anywhere close to that time, and the only system software changes were those performed by Windows Update.
Immediately after reboot, everything looks normal, but after several hours, a semi-transparent message saying 'Activate Windows' and 'Go to Settings to activate Windows' appears in the lower right corner of the first monitor (despite this, the computer continues to work normally, as far as I can tell.)
The activation settings window initially shows it not activated, and provides links to non-specific activation documentation. On returning to it a second time, I get a 'troubleshoot' option, an after this runs for a few seconds, it comes back saying that windows has been activated, and the original message disappears.
I used slmgr with /dlv and /xpr to check the status immediately after reboot, after the message appears, and after the activation. In each case, the response is the same (except for the Trusted Time value, which is always the current date and time):
/dlv:
Name: Windows(R), Professional edition
Description: Windows(R) Operating System, RETAIL channel
Application ID: [redacted]
Extended PID: [redacted]
Product Key Channel: Retail
Installation ID: [redacted]
Use License URL: https://activation-v2.sls.microsoft.com/SLActivateProduct/SLActivateProduct.asmx?configextension=Retail
Validation URL: https://validation-v2.sls.microsoft.com/SLWGA/slwga.asmx
Partial Product Key: [redacted]
License Status: Licensed
Remaining Windows rearm count: 1001
Remaining SKU rearm count: 1001
Trusted time: 7/18/2024 7:27:42 AM

/xpr:
Windows(R), Professional edition:
The machine is permanently activated.

The only thing that struck me as perhaps out-of-place is the product channel being 'Retail' (rather than something like 'OEM'), as this machine was originally delivered from Dell with Windows 8 Pro pre-installed (though I did not check at the time whether the license was classified as OEM or retail, and I do not recall what steps, if any, I had to follow in order to initially activate it.) Since then, the only OS upgrade has been the automatic one to Windows 10 (I don't recall when, but it was not immediately after the upgrade was initially offered, and for years afterwards, the current problem was absent.)
This machine is not eligible for upgrade to Windows 11.
The motherboard battery was replaced a couple of years ago, and the computer is not exhibiting any of the problems which accompanied the original battery failure. The activation problem did not occur either before or after the battery replacement (until recently, of course.)
At the time of the original problem, and also just now, sfc /scannow reported 'Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations' and dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth reported 'no component store corruption detected.'
Does anyone have a solution of this problem, or at least some further diagnostic steps that I could take?

So the machine originally ran Windows 8.  Was it an OEM license? The Product Key Channel is always going to say Retail regardless if it's an OEM machine or something you built yourself. How long ago did you upgrade to Windows 10? If you upgraded beyond 2016 that might explain your rolling activation status. [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment


The Activation Key is stored in the PC's firmware. Is there a chance the clock Li cell is failing, and might that cause it? 2. Try troubleshooting Windows 10 with SFC and DISM, and if that does not remedy the Activation issue, try reinstalling from ISO. Admittedly, this is a shotgun approach, but does no harm. 3. If you plan on continued use after Win10 end of support, consider another OS, such as Linux -- then Microsoft's Activation becomes moot.


Have you run Windows Update, and have you linked a Microsoft login to the user signed in? This shouldn't be necessary on a permanently activated motherboard hardware ID, as Windows ≥10 is auto activated via Windows Update (this is also saved to the Microsoft account linked to the user if one is linked). As to Win11, whether intentional by Microsoft or not I've repeatedly had instances of a machine activated with Win10 Pro activating successfully on Win11 upon first running Windows Update following the manual install of CPU chip set drivers (Windows Update can't install chipset drivers)

@JW0914 - Windows 11 isn’t relevant

@DrMoishePippik SFC and DISM ran without detecting problems when the activation problem first appeared, and I am repeating the tests now...

@DrMoishePippik sfc /scannow reports 'Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations' and dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth reports 'no component store corruption detected.'

What Windows 10 build are you on. I wonder if this is a locale issue of some sort. Reinstalling that build and doing an in-place upgrade might be helpful.

@Ramhound The build is 19043.2364. This is a build of version 21H1, and for some reason, Windows Update has never upgraded to a later version, even when I start it manually. While checking this, I noticed that it is licensed to a hotmail account which has been deleted by Microsoft. If that is the cause of the problem, I do not know how to proceed.

@JW0914 While I now normally use an account which is not linked to a Microsoft ID, this problem also occurs when I restart and then login with the same Microsoft-linked account as was used when the computer was set up on first boot.

@sdenham When logged in with the Microsoft account, have you run Windows Update after that? In order for the activation to be saved to a Microsoft Account, Windows Update first has to be run since this is how Windows  ≥10 is activated. Afterwards, you'll want to manually sync via the Microsoft account in Settings.

@JW0914 Thanks - I will try that as soon as I get a chance...

@sdenham If that doesn't resolve, I'd recommend reaching out directly to Microsoft's licensing customer service to have them resolve the issue on their end (you may want to do that anyways since this is a licensing issue on Microsoft's end). In regards to sfc and dism, they only fix system file corruption; even so, they weren't run in the correct order, as they're hierarchical commands, with each subsequent command relying entirely on the command before it (I explain here)

What do you mean your Microsoft Account was deleted?

@ramhound It is the hotmail account (the one to which the license has been granted) that seems to have been deleted: attempts to sign in get the response "that Microsoft account doesn't exist", and mail sent to it is undeliverable.
